# Cannot disable CollectionView items

Tags: maui, collectionview

In my .Net MAUI app, I have a CollectionView:

```
                         <CollectionView 
                            Margin="5,5,5,15"
                            ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Times}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTime, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            SelectionMode="Single">
                            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="3" />
                            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ContentView Padding="5" IsEnabled="{Binding IsAvailable}" >
                                        <Border
                                            StrokeThickness="1"
                                            StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10">
                                            <Label 
                                                Text="{Binding Time, StringFormat='{0:hh:mm tt}'}"
                                                Padding="10"
                                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                BackgroundColor="{Binding IsAvailable, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToTimeColorConverter}}"
                                                TextColor="Black" />
                                        </Border>
                                    </ContentView>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        </CollectionView>
```

Based on the value of IsAvailable property, some items of the CollectionView should be disabled, so that the user would not be able to select them. But for some reason, this does not happen.

I tried to hard-code IsEnabled to "False", but even then all items stay enabled. What am I missing?

Comment: the selectability of each row is behavior built into the CollectionView, not something you can toggle for individual rows.  Normally `IsEnabled` applies to UI elements that the user can interact with, like Buttons or Entrys

Comment: @Jason So it is definitely not possible?

Comment: @Jason Isn't there any work around?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to accomplish.  You could try un-setting the selected item in code, but I don't know how that would look visually

Comment: @Jason I just want nothing to happen if an item with IsAvailable = false is selected. I tried         private AppointmentTime _selectedTime;
    
        public AppointmentTime SelectedTime
        {
            get => _selectedTime;
            set
            {
                if(value.IsAvailable) 
                { 
                    _selectedTime = value;

                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedTimeDisplay));
                }
            }
        }
but the item still changes color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set it as null when the `SelectedItemIsAvailable = false`. Such as:

```
private AppointmentTime _selectedTime; 
public AppointmentTime SelectedTime 
{ 
  get => _selectedTime; 
  set 
    { 
      if(value.IsAvailable) 
      { 
         _selectedTime = value;
         OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedTimeDisplay)); 
      }else
      {
         _selectedTime = null;
         OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedTimeDisplay));
      } 
    } 
}
```

Or you can use the selection changed event to do that:

```
private void CollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((sender as CollectionView).SelectedItem != null &&((sender as CollectionView).SelectedItem as AppointmentTime).IsAvailable == false)
        {
            (sender as CollectionView).SelectedItem = null;
        }
    }
```

**Note:** This can't work for the windows when I tested it, it seems the collectionview's selected item will not reset when I called `(sender as CollectionView).SelectedItem = null` on the windows.